# Haskell: cannot construct the infinite type: t ~ t -> t

Tags: haskell

I wrote a function, which calculates catalan numbers, but it doesn't compile. I receive this error message:

> `• Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t ~ t -> t
>   Relevant bindings include
>   catalanNum :: t (bound at CatNum.hs:1:1)`

And here is my code:

```
catalanNum 0 = 1
catalanNum n =  div(2 *(catalanNum * (n-1)) * (2 * (n-1) + 1))(n + 1)
```

How can I eliminate this error?

Comment: First your declare `catalanNum` with a parameter, like it's a function. And then you multiply `catalanNum` by `(n-1)` like it's a number. So which is it?

Comment: Ach sorry that was very simple mistake.  Thanks for the hint

Comment: One question at a time, please. If the answer to your question leads to additional questions, post them separately, not by editing them into an existing post.

Comment: When facing such puzzling error messages, it's a good idea to write an explicit type annotation for the function. Once that is done, GHC can generate better error messages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> catalanNum 0 = 1
> catalanNum n =  div(2 *(catalanNum * (n-1)) * (2 * (n-1) + 1))(n + 2)
> ```

The problem in your code is here,

```
catalanNum * (n-1)
           ^
```

You are multiplying a function with an integer. You probably want to write,

```
catalanNum (n-1)
```

---

More importantly though, you should know how to find such errors. And even if you do not understand the error message, one thing should do is to trim down the problematic expression. The original expression is,

```
catalanNum n =  div (2 *(catalanNum * (n-1)) * (2 * (n-1) + 1)) (n + 2)
```

The `div` takes two arguments, in principle one of the is problematic, and it's likely to be the first since the second is rather simple. So trim it down.

```
catalanNum n =  2 *(catalanNum * (n-1)) * (2 * (n-1) + 1)
```

You can see this as three factors being multiplied,

```
2 
catalanNum * (n-1)
2 * (n-1) + 1
```

Look at them. If you don't see the error try them out. The first is irrelevant. The last works,

```
catalanNum n = 2 * (n-1) + 1
```

The middle one doesn't,

```
catalanNum n = catalanNum * (n-1)
```

This should now be relatively obvious.

---

After trimming your expression, if you still can't see the source of the error, add a type signature `catalanNum :: Int -> Int`. The error then becomes,

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Int -> Int’
> ```

You'd expect `catalanNum` to be an `Int` in order to multiply it, but it's of type `Int -> Int`.

Regarding the original error,

> ```
> Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t ~ t -> t
> ```

Without a type signature the type inference algorithm arrives at the conclusion that you have an expression whose type must be both, some `t` and `t->t` (written `t ~ t->t`). But then it would have infinite length and depth, since you'd also conclude,

```
 t ~ t->t
 t ~ t->t->t
 t ~ t->t->t->t 
 ...
```

and

```
 t ~ t->t
 t ~ (t->t)->t
 t ~ ((t->t)->t)->t
 ...
```

and combinations of both.

Comment: I have still another question can you please read above in my post and if you know answer give me a hint.

Comment: You can't pattern match with `n+1` any more. That was a controversial feature of the language that has since been removed. Controversial because `+` isn't a value constructor. So you can either pattern match with `0` and then with `n` (which matches all non-zeros, but also negative numbers), or you can use guards instead, i.e. a definition of the form `catNum n | n == 0 = ....`, and use a guard `| n > 0 = ...` for the positive case.